# Mysql CLI connects fine on localhost, but mysqli_connect resolves localhost to the machine name

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a seemingly straightforward call using mysqli_connect() that is failing due to host substitution of the name 'localhost'.

Example:

```
$username = 'foo';
$host = 'localhost';
$passwd = 'secret';

$link = mysqli_connect($host,$username, $passwd)...
```

Calling mysqli_connect with either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the host returns something like this:

> (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'foo'@'servername.mydomain.com'

I can connect using the same account with the locally-installed MySQL client just fine, so the user's permissions are valid:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'foo'@'localhost';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'foo'@'localhost'
```

Evidently mysqli_connect is trying to connect using the DNS name of the local machine instead of localhost.

I know I could opt to issue a grant for the user with the host explicitly defined as the machine name, or allow from all hosts, but neither of those options is acceptable in this instance. I need it to get it to work using localhost.

Related:
/etc/hosts defines localhost as follows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I also tried omitting the hostname entirely - by passing an empty string - and still got the same error.  According to the documentation I've seen, mysqli_connect() uses 'localhost:3306' as the default.

Comment: Also - nsswitch.conf has 'files' listed first as expected.   hosts:          files dns

Comment: Does it work when you use the value `null` as the hostname?

Comment: Also, check the `mysqli.default_socket` setting in `phpinfo();` and verify, that there is such a file in the file system.

Comment: As for using null for the host name parameter, that made no difference. I did set the default socket prior to posting, and that had no effect either.  Phpinfo does appear to reflect that setting as well: mysqli.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.  The socket file does exist at that location.  Also note that I put that setting in both the php.ini files (there's a separate one for apache and for cli), even though this particular script is being called only from the command line.

Comment: Since you call it from the command line, what is the result of running `php` via `strace`? Maybe it will show you if it tries to access the socket file or why it use a different connect routine.

Comment: Also tried passing the socket in the last parameter of the call to mysqli_connect(), but that made no difference.  I was able to determine that it is using that socket file, though, as it will complain with "No such file or directory" when intentionally pointed it to an invalid location.  I will try strace.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the path to the socket as the last argument to mysqli_connect() was probably working all along. A subsequent call to a remote database was also failing with an identical error, and I didn't notice until now that the error was occurring at a later line number.